# Conditional validation based on two inputs

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I have a model with two fields:

```
class Books(model.Models)
  status = models.IntegerField(
    null = False, blank = False, default = None,
    choices = [(1,'in stock'),(2,'out of stock'),(3,('other, specify below')]
  )
  other = models.TextField(
    blank = True, null = True,
  )
```

I then use a `RadioSelect` in my form widget to render `status` and all is well with the world.

However, I want to make `other` required if option 3 in `status` is selected. How can I do this server side via form validation?

E.g. the form should fail validation if choice `3:'other'` is selected and `other` remains blank or null.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to validate your data in the form, you should override the `clean` method and add your conditions there:

```
class YourForm(forms.Form):  # or a ModelForm
    #...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        status = cleaned_data.get("status")
        other = cleaned_data.get("other")

        if status == 3 and (not other):
            raise forms.ValidationError('Provide other field')
        return data
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do this at the `model` level to preserve the integrity? maybe a custom validator?

Comment: If you want to have the validation at **model** level, you should override the `save` method and add validation there or use a `signal`. You _can't_ use field validator as they **don't provide access to other field's data** (e.g. if you add it to the `other` field, you can't access the `status`).

Comment: This code raises the error `'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get'`?

Comment: @alias51 Sorry, It should be `cleaned_data` in the first line, updated.